# Compare two arrays and extract elements that are only present in one?

Tags: bash

What would be the easiest way to compare two arrays and extract elements that are present only in one of them?

i.e. - Whole - minus the set of common elements?

```
A = [2,3,4,5]
B = [1,3,4,5]
```

Extract 1,2 ?

Trying to script this in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a third array indexed by the values of the two arrays to be compared.  Assign 1 to each entry while adding the first array and 'or' 2 to each entry while adding the second array -- if the entry is in both original arrays this will set the value in the comparison array to 3.  N.B. this treats multiple entries in one of the source arrays as a single entry.

```
A=( 2 3 4 5 x x )
B=( 1 3 4 5 )

typeset -A C

for n in "${A[@]}" ; do C[$n]=1 ; done

for n in "${B[@]}" ; do (( C[$n] |= 2 )) ; done

for n in "${!C[@]}" ; do [[ ${C[$n]} -le 2 ]] && echo "$n" ; done

#  for n in "${!C[@]}" ; do [[ ${C[$n]} -gt 2 ]] && unset C[$n] ; done
#  uniques=( "${!C[@]}" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{delete a[$0]; next} {a[$0]} 
     END{for (i in a) print i}' <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}")
1
2
```

Using grep:

```
grep -vf <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}") && grep -vf <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}")
1
2
```

Using `comm` (assuming input array is already sorted):

```
comm -3 <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}")|tr -d '\t'
1
2
```

Comment: You should add a caveat that the `comm` variant you've posted would work only if the input arrays are sorted unless you're sure that it'd be obvious to the OP (and future readers).